# Oracle right join 3 tables but only has to match 1

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I'm not sure if the title is relevant to the question, bu i didn't found a better one.
Here's the problem - I have 4 table, let's say:

products (id, product_name),
priceA(product_id, price),
priceB(product_id, price),
priceC (product_id, price).

What i need to do is write a select that will show me only products that have prices in priceA OR priceB OR priceC OR in any combination of a,b,c

How could I do this ? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try something like this:

```
select p.id,
  p.name,
  a.price Price_A,
  b.price Price_B,
  c.price Price_C
from products p
left join pricea a
  on p.id = a.product_id
left join priceb b
  on p.id = b.product_id
left join pricec c
  on p.id = c.product_id
where a.price is not null
  or b.price is not null
  or c.price is not null
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85519/8)

Answer (score 3):

You could try using a UNION to combine the results:

```
select p.id,
   p.name,
   a.price
FROM products p INNER JOIN pricea a ON p.id = a.product_id
UNION
select p.id,
   p.name,
   b.price
FROM products p INNER JOIN priceb b ON p.id = b.product_id
UNION
select p.id,
   p.name,
   c.price
FROM products p INNER JOIN pricec c ON p.id = c.product_id
```

See SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85519/15

Comment: that's ok, but i need only one row for product e.g 2 product2 25 NULL  3